# Covert GIF code to GIF image or output to file?

Tags: javascript, php, gif, ups

I'm not exactly sure how to word this so apologies if the title is misleading.
I'm using UPS's web service to create a shipping label, this is returned as a GIF, but not as an image, instead as a long code:

```
R0lGODdheAUgA+cAAAAAAAEBAQICAgMDAwQEBAUFBQYGBgcHBwgICAkJCQoKCgsLCwwMDA0NDQ4ODg8PDxAQEBERERISEhMTExQUFBUVFRYWFhcXFxgYGBkZGRoaGhsbGxwcHB0dHR4eHh8fHyAgICEhISIiIiMjIyQkJCUlJSYmJicnJygoKCkpKSoqKisrKywsLC0tLS4uLi8vLzAwMDExMTIyMjMzMzQ0NDU1NTY2Njc3Nzg4ODk5OTo6Ojs7Ozw8PD09....... (etc)
```

My question is how do I use this to get an actual GIF image? preferably to output to file, and using either JavaScript or PHP.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string looks like base64-encoded data. Assuming it is, in fact, an image then you can decode it like this:

```
$encodedGif = 'R0lGODdheAUgA+cAAAAAAAEBAQICAgMDAwQEBAUFBQYGBgcHBw...';
$decodedGif = base64_decode($encodedGif, true);
if ($decodedGif === false) {
    die('Data has been corrupted. Unable to decode.');
}
```

Once you have the decoded data you can e.g. save it to a file:

```
$file = 'image.gif';
if ( ! file_put_contents($file, $decodedGif)) {
    die('Saving image did not work!');
}
```

Or you can output it to a browser as a GIF image:

```
header('Content-Type: image/gif');
die($decodedGif);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code that outputs this content (this is binary content of GIF image) has to announce in header to server that this content represents a GIF image (otherwise the server does not know how to represent this content). So your PHP code in header statement should define something like:

```
header('Content-Type: image/gif');
```

Look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagegif.php

Comment: That's a lot of `binary` values!

Comment: It is not binary data. It is *base64-encoded* binary data. Simply setting the content type will not work.

Comment: Look at your statenent "this is not binary data - it is base64-encoded binary data"!!! That's binary data for sure, I didn't say how it is encoded. And I did not say that putting header only is enough, I said that it "should define something like" directing OP where to find exact code.

Comment: Why did you down vote my answer?